# Avoid repetition on Django URLs

Tags: python, django

I'm making the Django tutorial at the official website and I'm currently [setting up URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) for the sample polling application we're creating.

As of now, my `polls/urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.votes, name='vote')
]
```

And I can't help but notice the repetition of `(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)` so I wonder if there's a simpler way to avoid this besides extracting it to a constant like `QUESTION_PATTERN = (?P<question_id>[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include a list of subpatterns, like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/', include([
        url(r'^$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^results/$', views.results, name='results'),
        url(r'^vote/$', views.votes, name='vote'),
    ]),
]
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for.